# Pandas - how to remove whitespace in datetime column conversion to avoid error?

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with columns like below:

```
                  Time             Offset
0  2019/07/15 11:47:24                NaN  
1  2019/07/15 11:47:47             0.0001   
2  2019/07/15 11:51:46             0.0004  
3  2019/07/15 11:51:51             0.0003   
4  2019/07/15 12:30:00                NaN
```

When I try to run `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')` on it, returned is `ValueError: time data 2019/07/15 nan doesn't match format specified`. Why is that `nan` present and / or how can I get rid of it to convert the column to datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter `errors=coerce` for convert values non matched format to `NaT`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
```

If possible trailing whitespaces use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove them:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'].str.strip(),format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
print (df)
                 Time  Offset
0 2019-07-15 11:47:24     NaN
1 2019-07-15 11:47:47  0.0001
2 2019-07-15 11:51:46  0.0004
3 2019-07-15 11:51:51  0.0003
4 2019-07-15 12:30:00     NaN
```

Then if need remove rows with `NaN`s in `Time` colum:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Time'])
```

Comment: I apologize the column should not have read `2019/07/15 Time` when originally posting. I updated my question

Comment: Thanks, `coerce` helped a lot